# redis is mostly single threaded. What do the threads other than the main thread (which processes client requests) do?

Tags: redis

The redis documentation says that redis is 'mostly' single threaded.
But is uses other threads to perform some background operations. What are those operations?

Answer (score 0):

See the Redis Docs :-[Redis](http://redis.io/topics/latency)

> Redis is mostly single threaded since actually from newer version it
>   uses threads in Redis in order to perform some slow I/O operations in
>   the background, mainly related to disk I/O.